# Can this be something else than a defect graphic card?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hardware-failure

Since a few days I'm experiencing strong issues with my ATI Radeon HD 7870. Often while playing games my two monitors turn into weird artefacts (with ongoing music for a moment) and then stay like this after a while. Only a reboot helps. I did watch the temperature and didn't notice anything special (temperature was mostly around 60 degree with around 40% fan activity)

I have a feeling that my graphic card might be broken now ...

I took some photos of my monitors after the crash. Can you tell me your opinion if it's the graphic card or something else? (I don't think it's the RAM since the music still runs a few seconds when the monitors turn into those said artefacts)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like hardware failure to me - try a different/known-good graphics adapter.

Comment: why did I get a downvote? did I do something wrong? If I did, I'm sorry

Comment: I think you are discounting the issue with RAM too easily.Ram that is faulty will also give you visible interuptions on your screen. That has happened to me when two sticks went bad. If you have multiple sticks, test them one at a time and do a memtest.

Comment: No need to be sorry -- it's just an arrow and a few made up Internet points, don't feel too bad. ;)  The down-vote is most likely because, aside from looking at the reported temperatures, and taking pictures, you've shown no research effort or attempts to resolve your own problem.  That tends to garner down-votes.  IE: if you think it's hardware, then test your theory and change the hardware.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to find out if he has to shell out for a new graphics card. Trying another graphics card to see if that's the problem would (for most people) mean shelling out for a new card.

Comment: If it's not a graphic card failure, it's most likely a RAM problem, so check with Memtest86+, or maybe a power supply failure. If you can't swap hardware to test, run a stress-test like OCCT to see if the problem appears only when using GPU or not at least, and you'll get nice plots of temp and voltages which can reveal something in some cases.

Comment: It is a bit odd looking for a simple crash of the GPU, but not odd for a really bad one :-)   One way to test the GPU "more" than the other parts of the system, would be to get Furmark or any other GPU torture testing software and break it , on demand. Doing that could make things worse, even permenent.  Your temps for the GPU processor thing are not high, but when referring to "ram" there is also the GPUs own ram, Thermal probe tests here show that the video ram can get hotter then the processor on some card designs.  Test for gpu processing, and test for "artifacts" which tests ram.